# Visual Studio LNK1104 with minimal example

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2015

I have set up two solutions to illustrate my problem, a total of three projects. I compile in Debug mode but my Problem still exists even if I compile in Release mode.

`MyRunnerCore.lib` requires `3rdParty.lib`. Why is that, what can I do against it?

Here is a Picture to explain how the folders are structured:

[image: SolutionLayout]

The idea is that I build the third party as a lib Project (works fine). Then I build the MyRunnerCore using the lib file in a cpp file only (works fine). Last not Least I Build a Console Application that uses the MyRunnerCore.lib (LNK1104). The output window reads:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyRunnerCore, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  Core.cpp
1>  MyRunnerCore.vcxproj -> C:\SO\MyRunner\Release\MyRunnerCore.lib
2>------ Build started: Project: MyRunner, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>  main.cpp
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '3rdParty.lib'
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here are the sourcefiles with annotations to point out in what Project I edited some settings.

ThirdPartyClass.cpp

```
#include "ThirdParyClass.hpp"
int ThirdParyClass::GenerateNumber()
{ return 4; }
```

ThirdPartyClass.hpp

```
#pragma once
class ThirdParyClass
{ public: int GenerateNumber(); };
```

main.cpp

```
//MyRunner Properties:
//Project Dependencies Added MyRunnerCore
//Include Directories Added $(SolutionDir)
//Library Directories Added $(OutDir)
#include <MyRunnerCore\Core.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "MyRunnerCore.lib")

int main() { Core c{}; return c.Run(); }
```

Core.cpp

```
#include "Core.h"
//MyRunnerCore Properties:
//Added To Include Path C:\SO\3rdParty
//Added To Library Path C:\SO\3rdParty\Debug
#include <3rdParty\ThirdParyClass.hpp>
#pragma comment(lib, "3rdParty.lib")

int Core::Run()
{ 
    ThirdParyClass tp{};
    return tp.GenerateNumber();
}
```

Core.h

```
#pragma once
class Core 
{ public: int Run(); };
```

Why does the Linker require 3rdParty.lib to link?

Am I missing a setting to make the Linker build `MyRunnerCore.lib` build without references to `3rdParty.lib`?

Comment: MSVC does not support a feature that combines static libraries. You will need to explicitly link to the third party lib and it must be in the paths that are set for the linker to look for libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tsandy wrote:

```
Librarian -> General -> Link Library Dependencies -> Yes
```

is correct. However using the following

```
#pragma comment (lib, ...)
```

is incompatible with that.

The library has to be included using

```
Librarian -> Additional Libraries -> 3rdParty.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

Thanks to tsandy for the Input.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the linker doesn't know where to find the file `ThirdParyClass.lib`. In the project settings for `MyRunner`, add the folder containing this file to `Additional Library Directories` under Linker.

Comment: Yes, that is true but the Linker should not have to know it. I want the Linker to include the ThirdPartyClass.lib in MyRunnerCore.lib so that I do not need to provide it when building MyRunner.

Comment: My understanding is that when `Core` compiles, it doesn't actually copy the implementation of `ThirdPartyClass` from `ThirdPartyClass.lib`. Instead, it leaves a placeholder saying "for the implementation of `ThirdPartyClass`, refer to `ThirdPartyClass.lib`". I'm not aware of any settings to get around this mechanism.

Comment: This is at the core of this question, do you have any documentation links?

Comment: In the `Core` project properties, it seems that setting `Link Library Dependencies` under Librarian to `Yes` will achieve the desired result.

Comment: Found it, Additional Libraries has to be set instead of the pragma comment. Can you update your answer with that so i can accept it?